# Unnecessary usage of data on my DB Springboot

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, jpa

So, I'm making an order project, I'm able to create products(id, created_at, deleted, price_in_euros, product_name), and with those products create orders. When I create an order, the products I chose to it become a cartItem(id, amount, productName, product_id, product_name, quantity, order_id). To make this clear, everytime I make an order I create a shoppingCartItem for each product I choose to order. This will saturate my db since if I want to make 2 orders with 30 products each, I'm making 60 different cartItems.
I need to find a way to use a cartItem for different orders if the amount is the same, because 4 cartItems, for example, can be the same product, but with different amounts.
My CloudProduct.java

```
package com.proj.my.model;

import jakarta.persistence.Column;
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.EntityListeners;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.GenerationType;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;

import java.sql.Date;

import org.hibernate.annotations.CreationTimestamp;
import org.hibernate.annotations.SQLDelete;
import org.hibernate.annotations.Where;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.support.AuditingEntityListener;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;

import jakarta.persistence.Table;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.Pattern;

@Entity
@Table(name="cloud_product_info")
@SQLDelete(sql = "UPDATE cloud_product_info SET deleted = true WHERE product_id=?")
@Where(clause = "deleted=false")
//@FilterDef(name="", parameters = @ParamDef(name="isDeleted", type = "boolean"))
//@Filter(name="deletedBookFilter", condition = "deleted = :isDeleted")
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(value = {"createdAt", "updatedAt"}, 
        allowGetters = true)



public class CloudProduct {

    public static Integer id;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer productId;
    @Column(unique=true)
    private String productName;
    private Float priceInEuros;
    @CreationTimestamp
    @Column(updatable = false, name = "created_at")
    private Date createdAt;
    private Boolean deleted = Boolean.FALSE;


    @JsonIgnore
    public Boolean getdeleted() {
        return deleted;
    }
    @JsonIgnore
    public void setdeleted(Boolean deleted) {
        this.deleted = deleted;
    }

    public CloudProduct(Integer productId, String productName, Float priceInEuros) {
        this.productId = productId;
        this.productName = productName;
        this.priceInEuros = priceInEuros;
    }

    public CloudProduct() {

    } 
    
    public Integer getProductId() {
        return productId;
    }
    public void setProductId(Integer productId) {
        this.productId = productId;
    }
    public String getProductName() {
        return productName;
    }
    public void setProductName(String productName) {
        this.productName = productName;
    }
    public Float getpriceInEuros() {
        return priceInEuros;
    }
    public void setProductPrice(Float priceInEuros) {
        this.priceInEuros = priceInEuros;
    }

    public Date getCreatedAt() {
        return createdAt;
    }

    public void setCreatedAt(Date createdAt) {
        this.createdAt = createdAt;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Product{" +
                "id=" + productId +
                ", name='" + productName + '\'' +
                ", price=" + priceInEuros +
                '}';
    }
}
```

My Order.java

```
package com.proj.my.model;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.annotations.CreationTimestamp;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.support.AuditingEntityListener;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;

import jakarta.persistence.CascadeType;
import jakarta.persistence.Column;
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.EntityListeners;
import jakarta.persistence.FetchType;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.GenerationType;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.JoinColumn;
import jakarta.persistence.OneToMany;
import jakarta.persistence.OneToOne;
import jakarta.persistence.Table;
import lombok.ToString;

@ToString
@Entity
@Table(name = "myorder")
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(value = {"createdAt"}, 
    allowGetters = true)  
public class Order {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
    @JoinColumn(name = "userId")
    private User user;


    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, targetEntity = ShoppingCart.class)
    @JoinColumn(name = "order_id")
    private List<ShoppingCart> cartItems;
    @CreationTimestamp
    @Column(updatable = false, name = "createdAt")
    private LocalDate createdAt;

    public LocalDate getCreatedAt() {
        return createdAt;
    }

    public void setCreatedAt(LocalDate createdAt) {
        this.createdAt = createdAt;
    }

    public Order() {
    }

    public Order(User user, LocalDate createdAt, List<ShoppingCart> cartItems) {
        this.user = user;
        this.cartItems = cartItems;
        this.createdAt = createdAt;
    }

    public Order(int Id, LocalDate createdAt, List<ShoppingCart> cartItems) {
        this.cartItems = cartItems;
        this.createdAt =  createdAt;
        this.id = Id;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setCustomer(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public List<ShoppingCart> getCartItems() {
        return cartItems;
    }

    public void setCartItems(List<ShoppingCart> cartItems) {
        this.cartItems = cartItems;
    }
}
```

My shoppingCart.java

```
package com.proj.my.model;


import org.hibernate.annotations.NotFound;

import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.GenerationType;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
/*@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
*/
@Entity
public class ShoppingCart {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    private Integer productId;
    
    private String productName;

    private int quantity;
    
    private float amount;

    public ShoppingCart() {
    }

    public ShoppingCart(Integer productId, String productName, int quantity, float amount) {
        this.productId = productId;
        this.productName = productName;
        this.quantity = quantity;
        this.amount = amount;
    }

    public ShoppingCart(Integer productId, int quantity) {
        this.productId = productId;
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }

    public ShoppingCart(String productName, int quantity) {
        this.productName = productName;
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Integer getProductId() {
        return productId;
    }

    public void setProductId(Integer productId) {
        this.productId = productId;
    }

    public String getProductName() {
        return productName;
    }

    public void setProductName(String productName) {
        this.productName = productName;
    }

    public int getQuantity() {
        return quantity;
    }

    public void setQuantity(int quantity) {
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }

    public float getAmount() {
        return amount;
    }

    public void setAmount(float amount) {
        this.amount = amount;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ShoppingCart{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", productId=" + productId +
                ", productName='" + productName + '\'' +
                ", quantity=" + quantity +
                ", amount=" + amount +
                '}';
    }
}
```

My orderService.java

```
package com.proj.my.service;

import com.proj.my.model.Order;
import com.proj.my.model.CloudProduct;
import com.proj.my.model.ShoppingCart;
import com.proj.my.repository.OrderRepository;
import com.proj.my.repository.CloudProductRepository;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

@Service
public class OrderService {

    private OrderRepository orderRepository;
    private CloudProductRepository cloudProductRepository;

    public OrderService(OrderRepository orderRepository, CloudProductRepository cloudProductRepository) {
        this.orderRepository = orderRepository;
        this.cloudProductRepository = cloudProductRepository;
    }

    public Order getOrderDetail(int orderId) {
        Optional<Order> order = this.orderRepository.findById(orderId);
        return order.isPresent() ? order.get() : null;
    }
    
   public List<Order> getAllOrderDetail(LocalDate dataaa) {
        return orderRepository.findAllByCreatedAt(dataaa);
    }

    public float getCartAmount(List<ShoppingCart> shoppingCartList) {

        float totalCartAmount = 0f;
        float singleCartAmount = 0f;

        for (ShoppingCart cart : shoppingCartList) {

            String cloudProductName = cart.getProductName();
            Optional<CloudProduct> product = cloudProductRepository.findByProductName(cloudProductName);
            if (product.isPresent()) {
                CloudProduct cloudproduct = product.get();
                singleCartAmount = cart.getQuantity() * cloudproduct.getpriceInEuros();
                
                totalCartAmount = totalCartAmount + singleCartAmount;
                cart.setProductId(cloudproduct.getProductId());
                cart.setAmount(singleCartAmount);
                cloudProductRepository.save(cloudproduct);
            }
        }
        return totalCartAmount;
    }

    public Order saveOrder(Order order) {
        return orderRepository.save(order);
    }
}
```

My orderController.java

```
package com.proj.my.controller;

import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.proj.my.dto.OrderDTO;
import com.proj.my.dto.ResponseOrderDTO;
import com.proj.my.model.CloudProduct;
import com.proj.my.model.Order;
import com.proj.my.model.ShoppingCart;
import com.proj.my.model.User;
import com.proj.my.repository.CloudProductRepository;
import com.proj.my.service.CloudProductService;
import com.proj.my.service.OrderService;
import com.proj.my.service.UserService;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class OrderController {

    private OrderService orderService;
    private CloudProductService cloudProductService;
    private UserService userService;
    @Autowired
    private CloudProductRepository cloudProductRepository;


    public OrderController(OrderService orderService, CloudProductService cloudProductService, UserService userService) {
        this.orderService = orderService;
        this.cloudProductService = cloudProductService;
        this.userService = userService;
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/getOrder/{orderId}")
    public ResponseEntity<Order> getOrderDetails(@PathVariable int orderId) {
        Order order = orderService.getOrderDetail(orderId);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(order);
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/getOrders/{dataaa}")
    public List<Order> getAllOrderDetails(@PathVariable LocalDate dataaa) {
        return orderService.getAllOrderDetail(dataaa);
    }

    @PostMapping("/placeOrder")
    public ResponseEntity<?> placeOrder(@RequestBody OrderDTO orderDTO) {

        ResponseOrderDTO responseOrderDTO = new ResponseOrderDTO();
        List<ShoppingCart> shoppingCartList = orderDTO.getCartItems();
        ShoppingCart shoppingCart;
        for (ShoppingCart cart : shoppingCartList) {
            String cloudProductName = cart.getProductName();
            Optional<CloudProduct> product = cloudProductRepository.findByProductName(cloudProductName);
            if (product.isPresent()){
                float amount = orderService.getCartAmount(orderDTO.getCartItems());
                if(amount > 0){
                    User user = new User(orderDTO.getuserEmail());
                    
                    Integer userIdFromDb = userService.isUserPresent(user);

                    if (userIdFromDb != null) {
                        user.setUserId(userIdFromDb);
                    }else{
                        user = userService.createUser(user);
                    }
                    LocalDate createdAt = LocalDate.now(); 
                    

                    Order order = new Order(user, createdAt, orderDTO.getCartItems());

                    order = orderService.saveOrder(order);

                    responseOrderDTO.setAmount(amount);

                    responseOrderDTO.setDate(com.proj.my.util.DateUtil.getCurrentDateTime());
                    
                    responseOrderDTO.setOrderId(order.getId());


                    return ResponseEntity.ok(responseOrderDTO);
                }
                else{
                    return new ResponseEntity<>("Can't create an order without products.", HttpStatus.OK);
                }
            }
            else{
                return new ResponseEntity<>("No Product with such name found.", HttpStatus.OK);
            }
        }
        return null;
    }}
```

Let me know if you need the rest of the services and, or controllers of the other 2 entities.
How can I do this ?

Comment: 60 rows is nothing for a database. A database is able to easily handle millions of rows within seconds. Running a select query on a table with 35 million entries takes less than a second

Comment: I understand, but can't I make this simpler in terms of cartItems created ?

Comment: There is no sense in that. Every cart item should be unique for each order. If at all, you can make a `@ManyToMany` relationship between `Order` and `ShoppingCart`. This however is only ever useful if you have exactly the same values for a `ShoppingCart`. And you will need to adjust your database

Comment: Okay Sir, you made me relax a bit ahah I was kinda worried.